# "translation_missing" when using default_locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview, actionviewhelper, rails-i18n

I'm trying to show a text in spanish using locales, but it keeps using english as default. My code:

```
# config/application.rb
config.i18n.default_locale = :es

# config/locales/es.yml
es:
  sections:
    fashion: Moda

# haml template
= t("sections.fashion")
```

In the view is generating the following html: `<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.sections.fashion">Fashion</span>`. Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the gem: rails-i18n

In my case it was the solution.

https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n